# Difference between inculpate and incriminate?

Tags: meaning

While they appear to have the same meaning, is there an actual difference between the two words?

Are there situations where one is preferred over the other?

Comment: Which one do you tend to use more often, and why?

Comment: I often use incriminate, but the reason behind this is more due to personal preference. I often find myself using the opposite of inculpate, i.e., exculpate, hence wondering whether there are actual uses for inculpate over incriminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inculpate**, to all intents and purposes, became rare (save in formal legal writing) around the late 19th century when **incriminate** took over from it. Rhetorically, **inculpate** is usually used in the context of a contrast to **exculpate**. See [Google Ngrams for inculpate, incriminate](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculpate%2Cincriminate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculpate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincriminate%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinculpate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cincriminate%3B%2Cc0)

The OED gives

> **Inculpate**: 1. transitive. To bring a charge against; **to accuse; to blame, find fault with.**
>
> 1799   S. Turner Hist. Anglo-Saxons I. iii. iii. 173   *Gildas inculpates him for having destroyed his uncle.*

in which inculpate can be used, as shown, as a close synonym for *blame, accuse or find fault with [someone]:*

To **incriminate** lacks this meaning.

Comment: It sounds to me like, generally, you *incriminate* yourself when you do something criminal, and then someone *inculpates* you when they charge you with culpability for it.

Comment: Incriminate yourself, indeed, but also: *those evidences incriminate you/him, etc.*,@Anonym.